# Scroll a div inside a td

Tags: css

I'd like to scroll the div in the 2rd cell. But it just won't work! (Tried in Chrome). Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
<style>
body{height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
</style>

<table width=100%>
<tr>
    <td id="menu">
        <div>
        ... 
        </div>
    </td>

    <td id="list">
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
        ... 
        </div>
    </td>

    <td id="details">
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please post a working example, preferably on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com). in its current form, you question isn't very likely to get some answers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason nothing is scrolling is because the height on the  cells are auto-adjust, along with the DIV container. Everything needs to have set heights in order for scrolling to work. See an example I made below.

http://jsfiddle.net/QJW7w/